# Trying to get setTimeout(); to work in a loop.

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code, i'm trying to get it so when the button is clicked there is a chance that you will chop down the tree, when you don't chop down the tree it uses a timer to attempt to do it again (after 1 second). Once the tree does get chopped down it's suppose to set a 5 second timer that makes it "inactive" until the timer is up then it will be "active" again. Which requires you to click the button again to begin the cycle over.

```
    var woodcuttingLevel = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var treeSpawn;
    var reClick;

    function cutTree(){
        var randomEvent = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1);

        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "chop " + count;
        count += 1;

        switch(randomEvent){
            case 1:
             //add a log
             document.getElementById("treeActive").innerHTML = "inActive1";
             treeSpawn=setTimeout(function(){spawnTree()},5000);
            break;
            case 2:
            //add a log if over level 5
            if(woodcuttingLevel >= 5){
             document.getElementById("treeActive").innerHTML = "inActive2";
             treeSpawn=setTimeout(function(){spawnTree()},5000);
            }
             reClick=setTimeout(function(){reClick()},1000);
            break;
            case 3:
            //add a log if over level 8
            if(woodcuttingLevel >= 8){
             document.getElementById("treeActive").innerHTML = "inActive3";
             treeSpawn=setTimeout(function(){spawnTree()},5000);
            }
             reClick=setTimeout(function(){reClick()},1000);
            break;
            case 4:
            //add a log if over level 13
            if(woodcuttingLevel >= 13){
             document.getElementById("treeActive").innerHTML = "inActive4";
             treeSpawn=setTimeout(function(){spawnTree()},5000);
            }
             reClick=setTimeout(function(){reClick()},1000);
            break;
            case 5:
            //add a log if over level 17
            if(woodcuttingLevel >= 17){
             document.getElementById("treeActive").innerHTML = "inActive5";
             treeSpawn=setTimeout(function(){spawnTree()},5000);
            }
             reClick=setTimeout(function(){reClick()},1000);
            break;
            case 6:
            //add a log if over level 22
            if(woodcuttingLevel >= 22){
             document.getElementById("treeActive").innerHTML = "inActive6";
             treeSpawn=setTimeout(function(){spawnTree()},5000);
            }
             reClick=setTimeout(function(){reClick()},1000);
            break;
            case 7:
            //add a log if over level 30
            if(woodcuttingLevel >= 30){
             document.getElementById("treeActive").innerHTML = "inActive7";
             treeSpawn=setTimeout(function(){spawnTree()},5000);
            }
             reClick=setTimeout(function(){reClick()},1000);
            break;
            default:
            //error
        }

    }

    function spawnTree(){
        document.getElementById("treeActive").innerHTML = "Active";
        clearInterval(treeSpawn);
        clearInterval(reClick);
    }

    function reClick(){
        cutTree();
    }
```

The reClick() function doesn't work, i'm not really sure why. Can anyone lead me to an answer? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Tip: `function(){ fn() } === fn`

Comment: Not sure I follow, I was going off of this myVar=setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);. What is the (=== fn) part?

Comment: I mean that `setTimeout(function(){spawnTree()},5000);` is the same as `setTimeout(spawnTree,5000)`. Just a general tip.

Comment: You don't need to do `function(){spawnTree()}` because `spawnTree` is already a function reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reClick` function doesn't work because it doesn't exist any more when you try to call it.

You have used the same name for the variable that holds the identifier for the timeout, so it will replace the function when you start the timeout. Use a different name for the variable. Change:

```
var reClick;
```

to:

```
var reClickTimer;
```

and all of the:

```
reClick=setTimeout(function(){reClick()},1000);
```

to:

```
reClickTimer=setTimeout(function(){reClick()},1000);
```

and:

```
clearInterval(reClick);
```

to:

```
clearInterval(reClickTimer);
```

---

Side note: As the `setTimeout` method takes a callback function as the first parameter, you don't need a function expression that calls the function, you can use the function reference itself:

```
reClickTimer=setTimeout(reClick,1000);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much for your help. A very rookie mistake on my part!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you perform this assignment

```
reClick=setTimeout(function(){reClick()},1000);
```

You are essentially deleting your `reClick` function definition and replacing it with `setTimeout`'s result, which is a "id" that identifies the running timeout operation.
You will need to rename your variable defined on top with `var reClick` by something like `var reClickTimeout` , that you can use like this

```
reClickTimeout=setTimeout(function(){reClick()},1000);
```

You will of course also need to replace all the other misplaced references like

```
clearInterval(reClick); -> clearInterval(reClickTimeout);
```